# How to increment a particular character in string (Java)

Tags: java

suppose i have a **string s1 = "abcd";**

**output should be s1 = "abca";**

I want to decrement/increment  the last character in the string so that it matches the first character of the string .
Since String doesn't allow to modify the data
How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Since, as you noted, `String` is immutable you will have to perform an assignment. I'd do a `substring()` and then concatenate the first letter. Something like

```
String s1 = "abcd";
s1 = s1.substring(0, s1.length() - 1) + s1.charAt(0);
System.out.println(s1);
```

Output is (as requested)

```
abca
```

[JLS-4.2.1. Integral Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) does document that `char` is an integral type. That allows you to do something like

```
public static String modifyCharInString(String in, int index, int ammount) {
    if (in == null || in.isEmpty() || index < 0 || index >= in.length()) {
        return in;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(in);
    sb.setCharAt(index, (char) (in.charAt(index) + ammount));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And then you an call it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "abcd";
    s1 = modifyCharInString(s1, s1.length() - 1, -3);
    System.out.println(s1);
}
```

Output is (again)

```
abca
```

Comment: At the back end it should work like 

abcd -> abcc -> abcb -> abca

Comment: @AbhyudheySharma What does that mean? You want an algorithm that can decrement an arbitrary character in a `String`? Because your example, and your title, and your comment are very confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion 
Yes I want an algo that can decrement an arbitrary character in a String .
Thanx in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

For editing Strings you can use StringBuilder class. This allows you to get better performance, than using substring().

```
    String oldString = "abcd";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(oldString);
    sb.setCharAt(sb.length() - 1, sb.charAt(0));
    String newString = sb.toString();
```